# Re-challenge authenticated users in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm running into some issues with the authentication pipeline in ASP.NET Core. My scenario is that I want to issue a challenge to a user who is already authenticated using OpenID Connect and Azure AD. There are multiple scenarios where you'd want to do that, for example when requesting additional scopes in a AAD v2 endpoint scenario.

This works like a charm in ASP.NET MVC, but in ASP.NET Core MVC the user is being redirected to the Access Denied-page as configured in the cookie authentication middleware. (When the user is not logged in, issuing a challenge works as expected.)

After a couple of hours searching the web and trying different parameters for my middleware options, I'm beginning to suspect that either I'm missing something obvious, or this behavior is by design and I need to solve my requirement some other way. Anyone any ideas on this?

EDIT: the relevant parts of my Startup.cs look like this:

```cs
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthentication(
            SharedOptions => SharedOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // <snip...>

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme });

        var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            ClientId = ClientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"],
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44374/",
            TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false
            }
        };
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
    }
```

And the Action looks like this:

```cs
    public void RefreshSession()
    {
        HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
    }
```

Comment: Did you consider using AuthenticationSchemes? If you want to ignore cookieauthentication for some action, you can use Authorize attribute with another scheme such as azureaadscheme.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help either. I can set schemes all I want and specify one for the challenge, but the cookie authentication is still somehow involved in handling it. And note, I'm not using the Authorize attribute. The user is already authenticated, and I manually issue a challenge.

Comment: Could you post startup.cs and action method?

Comment: I have run into the exact same problem today, did you ever found an answer to this question?

Comment: Same here... Did someone find the "obvious" point we are missing? I failed to find find any issue on github (even a closed one).

Comment: @VolatileCoder, did Spi's answer answer the question? I'm the author of the article Spi linked, and the problem definitely is the ChallengeBehavior, which is Automatic by default, meaning it will trigger a Forbidden response if the user was authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

I found a hint and the solution here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/912.
ChallengeBehavior.Unauthorized is the "key".

This post gives the current (november 2016 - ASPNet 1.0.1) workaround: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-b2c-with-aspnet-core

You'll need a new ActionResult to be able to call the AuthauticationManager.ChallengeAsync with the ChallengeBehavior.Unauthorized behavior.

Once the issue https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5187 will be sucessfully closed, this should be integrated.

I tested it and it worked perfectly well (my goal was simply to extend Google scopes on a per user basis).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to sign out:

public void RefreshSession()
{
      HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
      HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
      HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
}
```

Comment: That does not work either. What does work is to issue the SignOut and redirect to another action that in turn issues the Challenge. But obviously that means another roundtrip and is therefore suboptimal. Issuing a challenge immediately after the signout overwrites whatever response the signout would have created.

Comment: I am not sure it  solves your problem but i added remote signout, see updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't make a difference. Without a redirect in between, the last statement dictates what the response looks like, so this is in effect the same thing as issuing a challenge without any of the signout stuff. And that in itself (the last statement determines the response) is fine; it's just that the Challenge does not generate a response that behaves like I would expect based on ASP.NET vPrev experiences.