# Asking an authenticated user to type their credentials again in order to access certain secure features

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm new to identity server 4. I have a .NET Core project where one of the business requirements is that authenticated users will be forced to enter their credentials in order to submit certain types of data-changing requests to the server. Similar to how some websites require users to enter their password to access account settings, except the user's username and password would be required every time a request to these certain endpoints is made.

What I was thinking about doing is having the user submit their username and password to the .NET Core web API where it would then be sent to the ID4 server over a back-channel.

How do I configure this back-channel? Do I need any special middleware on the ID4 server to check usernames and passwords? It's currently set up to use cookies. Are there any useful libraries for .NET Core to send a user's login credentials to the ID4 server, or do I have to manually set up the HTTP requests? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: Exposing credentials to clients / apis does not increase security, In fact the opposite is true. Also, reentering credentials does not guarantee that this is the actual user. Instead I would implement an additional step, like sending a link to the known email address or sms a code.

Comment: I know, but these are the requirements. The business requirements don't even require the authenticating user to be the logged in user - as long as the username and password works. They just want to make sure whoever is accessing this part of the API knows what they're doing. It's less about authentication and more about signing off on an action.

Comment: That's a bit odd. If an authenticated user is using someone elses credentials then that would be a red flag. But if it doesn't matter whether the user is the authenticated user, then don't use IdentityServer for that. You can accomplish the same by entering an email address (of a registered user) and clicking a link to gain access. I don't see why that wouldn't meet the business requirement.

Comment: Different industries have unique business requirements. For us it's a terminal used inside an organization that someone logs into, but that someone else might come along and use. But in order to submit certain forms, the current user must "sign" on their changes by entering their credentials. Password check was explicitly a business requirement by the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ResourceOwnerCredentialsFlow` if you need a programmatic interface into `Identity Server 4` using user's credentials. So basically, you would set up your api project as a client in the IDS4 config and then you would need to implement `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`.

More info about this in [Identity Server 4 docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/resource_owner.html).

I do, however, think that you might be going about this the wrong way. What you are looking to achieve is to basically challenge the user for credentials whenever they try to access some special MVC action that you would want the user to reenter their credentials. This should be possible to achieve by firstly removing cookie authentication on your IDS4 (if you really want the users to always re-enter their credentials) and then configuring your ASP.NET Core app cookie authentication scheme to redirect to the identity provider should the user be trying to access your special MVC controller action. I haven't personally tried this approach so this part of the answer is purely theoretical, but just doing a quick google search on the subject gave the below links which might help you out as well.

[How to force re authentication between ASP Net Core 2.0 MVC web app and Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50596862/how-to-force-re-authentication-between-asp-net-core-2-0-mvc-web-app-and-azure-ad?rq=1)

[Re-challenge authenticated users in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344921/re-challenge-authenticated-users-in-asp-net-core)

[Forcing reauthentication with Azure AD](https://hajekj.net/2017/03/06/forcing-reauthentication-with-azure-ad/)

Comment: Further to the above - using the `prompt=login` or `max_age` parameters and `auth_time` claim is the combo you need. You can then enforce in your client app that the `auth_time` claim is within a given window (let's say 5 minutes) before allowing certain things to change.